# HashMap from Room Persistance Library

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

I want to get a key-pair object from my sql, so how can I make sometime like this

```
@Query("SELECT id,name FROM table")
HashMap<Integer, String> getValues();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You better off creating a Pojo to encapsulate your pair, that's the way they do in the samples, which I imagine is the right way to do it.

```
class  POJO {
    String name;
    int id;
}

@Query("SELECT id,name FROM table")
List<POJO> getValues();
```

Comment: sometimes what you _need_ is not the right way to do it